# Custom log entry string formatting in NLog?

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I'm new to NLog and wanted to know if there's a way I write log entries formatted in some custom way ? For example, here are some things I want to do to my log entries:

--> Have nested log entry messages (excluding log entry metadata) to make the depth of the logging call stack easier to follow. This can be done by indenting the log entry string proportionally by how deep you are in the logging call stack

--> Log a "change ID" (basically some sort of ID linked to some request that's being processed) with all relevant log entries

I know NLog has some templates you can use and stuff, but I would prefer having more control, in the form of a custom formatting class or something, which would intercept the logging request every time I do `Log.Info(...)`, and then format my log entry string appropriately according to the behavior I choose.

Is this possible ?

EDIT:

Here's the contents of my current NLog.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd" autoReload="true" throwExceptions="true" internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
   <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.log" />
      <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logconsole" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: For the "change ID" then you you can insert correlationid into `LogEventInfo.Properties` or make use of `CorrelationManager.ActivityId`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context

Answer (score 1):

One way is create a custom layout renderer.

There are 2 options to do this:

### Lambda method

Create a lambda methods and register before loading other NLog things (beware of statics), e.g. in main().

The lambda receives a [LogEventInfo](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.7.0/html/T_NLog_LogEventInfo.htm), which includes the following properties: Level, Message (unformated), FormattedMessage, Parameters  (send to Log.Info), optional Exception and properties (named parameters)

```cs
//Create ${message-length}

// NLog 4.7+ syntax
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
   s.RegisterLayoutRenderer("message-length", (logevent) => logEvent.FormattedMessage.Length)
);
```

### Class

If you need more control and options, you could also create a class that inherits from NLog.LayoutRenderers.LayoutRenderer

#### 1. Setup

```cs
/// <summary>
/// E.g. usage:  ${MyFormatter:MyLayout:${uppercase}} or ${MyFormatter:${uppercase}}
/// </summary>
[LayoutRenderer("MyFormatter")]
public class MyFormatterLayoutRenderer: LayoutRenderer
{
    [RequiredParameter]
    public Layout MyLayout { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var text = MyLayout.Render(logEvent);
        builder.Append(text);
    }
}
```

#### 2. Register

You need to [register the layout renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component):

```cs
// NLog 4.7+ syntax
NLog.LogManager.Setup().SetupExtensions(s =>
   s.RegisterLayoutRenderer<MyNamespace.MyFormatterLayoutRenderer>("MyFormatter")
);
```

#### 3. Usage

Use it as follows, set the layout attribute of a target. For example:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="logfile.log" layout="${message-length} - ${level} - ${message} - ${exception}"  />
<target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" layout="${message-length} - ${level} - ${message} - ${exception}" />
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however as I'm completely new to NLog, can you add the following to your code (for the second scenario where you're creating a custom class): 1) programmatic example usage of logging something, 2) some basic custom string formatting behavior in the layout render class, 3) what to change in the NLog.config file to reference my custom layout renderer ?

Comment: Maybe share a striped version of your current config? Then I could add it there in my answer

Comment: Sure, I just added it to my question.

Comment: Updated it! Hope it helps you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't see how this is helpful for me .. Can you kindly add the items I mentioned in my comment above to your answer ? It will help me understand how to use the `MyFormatterLayoutRenderer` class for some custom log string formatting ...

Comment: Maybe read this https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial. Your questions are too broad for now.